# Problem with code that orders numbers from 100 to 200 and tells me the amount of unique numbers imput

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, for-loop

I'm doing a code which tells the user to input an undetermined amount of numbers between 100 and 200. The program tells me the amount of unique numbers and then orders the numbers imputed. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *numbers, int count) {
   for (int m = 0; m < count; m++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count - m - 1; j++) {
            if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) {
               int temp = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                numbers[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printA(int *numbers, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int numbers[101] = {0}; // using an array to keep track of numbers between 100 and 200
    int input, count = 0;

    printf("Enter numbers between 100 and 200 (enter a number outside this range to   finish):\n");

    while (1) {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if (input < 100 || input > 200) {
            break;
        }
        if (numbers[input - 100] == 0) {
            count++;
            numbers[input - 100] = input;
        }
    }

    printf("\nTotal unique numbers entered: %d\n", count);

    sort(numbers, count);
    printA(numbers, count);

    return 0;
}
```

The program tells me the amount of unique numbers input correctly, but fails to order them. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: By the way, if you use `scanf` to read input, you *always* need to check what it [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Your `numbers` array is already in ascending order with a lot of zeroes mixed in. If you print the whole thing while skipping zeroes, you don't need the `sort` thingy.

Comment: If you want to understand what is going on, try printing out the whole `numbers` table. Then take a look at its first `count` items. What do you see?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I had wrongly assumed a buffer overflow vulnerability. I have removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

The most important issue in the OP code is that `printA` and `sort` are called with `count` as parameter which is then used as the array size inside the function. However, `count` is counting the amount of numbers entered, not the size of the `numbers` array.

The `numbers` array holds all unique numbers entered in numerical order, so there is no need to sort, only to exclude the 0-entries (corresponding to numbers in the range which were *not* entered).

Finally, the return code of `scanf()` should be checked to verify that a new number was actually received.

All in all, the code can be adjusted as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printA(int *numbers, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(numbers[i]) printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int numbers[101] = {0}; // using an array to keep track of numbers between 100 and 200
    int input, count = 0;

    printf("Enter numbers between 100 and 200 (enter a number outside this range to   finish):\n");

    while (1) {
        if(scanf("%d", &input) != 1)
        {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");  // Remove invalid input from buffer
            continue;
        }
        if (input < 100 || input > 200) {
            break;
        }
        if (numbers[input - 100] == 0) {
            count++;
            numbers[input - 100] = input;
        }
    }

    printf("\nTotal unique numbers entered: %d\n", count);

    printA(numbers, sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To nicely illustrate pain points of the original code I've created modified versions of the code:

Note that [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/zE8zx536d) is your code.  It is only slightly modified in a few small ways:
1.) `SIZE_ARRAY` is defined as 100; reusable and easily-recognizable.
2.) We print the entire array by sending `SIZE_ARRAY` to the printing routines.  This will illustrate all the empty (zero) array slots.
3.) `GetRandom(100, 200)` is employed to simulate user entry -- a very convenient convention for testing.

Please note the before and after print out.  The array is riddled with zeros throughout: the array data is non-contiguous.
Also, because `count` (20) is sent to `sort()`, only the first 20 array indexes can be sorted.  If you run the code at the link you'll see that some indexes are sorted, but only the 1st 20.

Now, please see [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/PdTGsh5a8) -- it is the same code with one small change: `SIZE_ARRAY` is given to `sort()`, so `sort()` can now sort the entire array.  To be sure, please note the 2nd print out is nicely sorted data.

What follows is just one more of many possible solutions.  It adjusts the way the numbers are stored: they are now stored contiguously (no gaps), and `sort()` -- when given variable `count` -- will be able to sort *all* the data.   Buffer over-run protection is also added to the loop in `main()` via variable `count`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *numbers, int count) 
{
int m, j;

   for (m = 0; m < count; m++) {
        for (j = 0; j < count - m - 1; j++) {
            if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) {
               int temp = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                numbers[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printA(int *numbers, int count) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main() 
{
    int numbers[101] = {0}; // using an array to keep track of numbers between 100 and 200
    int input, count = 0;
    printf("Enter numbers from 100 to 200 inclusive (enter a number outside this range to finish):\n");

    while (count < 101) /* Updated -- protect from array over-run */ 
    {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if (input < 100 || input > 200) {
            break;
        }
        /* Updated -- numbers are not pre-sorted during storage.
        * Now the sort function can reach all the data entries.*/
        numbers[count++] = input;
    }
    printf("\nTotal unique numbers entered: %d\n", count);

    sort(numbers, count);
    printA(numbers, count);

    return 0;
}
```